# Laravel extending App\User and call with \Auth::user()->mymethod()

Tags: laravel, model, extend

In my project I use the default App\User.php model like this:

```
namespace App;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I have created a package "shop" and want to extend the User model.
For example:

```
namespace Pixiebox\Shop;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cart extends Authenticatable
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'cart_posts', 'cart_id', 'post_id')->withPivot(['listtype', 'qty']);
    }
}
```

Pixiebox\Shop\src\Shop\User.php

```
namespace Pixiebox\Shop;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function cart()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Pixiebox\Shop\Cart', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

If I do

```
$wishlist = \Auth::user()->cart()->with(['posts' => function($subquery){
    return $subquery->wherePivot('listtype', 'wishlist');
}])->first();
```

it returns "Call to undefined method App\User::cart()".
Because it's an optional package I don't want to put the methods in \App\User.php but in the package where it belongs. Is there another way around?

Comment: You don't actually extend `App\User` but `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`. Plus, extending doesn't  use your class anywhere in code

Answer (score 3):

You can set within `config/auth.php` under `providers` model which is to be used for authentication:

```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class, // <---
        ],
    ...
```